# Processing AJAX response consisting of two logically separate HTML markup sections

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am having a data response consisting of two entirely separate sections from a presentation point of view but which are logically connected on the server side and therefore are more efficiently generated in one AJAX call. The two sections have to populate two separate divs. My question is what is the most optimal method to do this?

OPTION1: Generate the response on the server side as:

```
  <div id="first_section">
   ...
  </div>
  <div id="second_section">
   ...
  </div>
```

Load the response in a dummy div as in $('#dummydiv').html(response) and then extract individual sections as in $('#first_section).html() and $('#second_section).html() and use their return string to populate the target div as in

```
  $('#target_div1').html( $('#first_section).html());
  $('#target_div2').html( $('#second_section).html());
```

OPTION 2: Write JS to process the response as one big string, use some regular expressions to parse and return the two separate sections as two individual strings to be assigned to the .html() of the target divs.

OPTION 3: Have two separate AJAX calls, one for each div (expensive duplicate option as the server-side computing is very connected).

OPTION 4: Any suggestions?

Since this is something that I need to do consistently in the application, the right approach is very important. Any comments OR A DIFFERENT APPROACH ALTOGETHER will be appreciated.

**UPDATE**: The response is presentation (lot of markup generated on the server side to the data) and not data intensive. JSON would be a wrong choice I think as it would require markup to be generated on the client side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach would be return html segments that have same ID as the elements you want to populate. You can create a jQuery object from the response, then use `find` to get html needed for each section. This response jQuery object never gets inserted in the DOM.

```
<div> <!--- root element wrapper, could even be full page which is excessive but works -->
<div id="first_section">
 <!--- new content -->
 </div>
  <div id="second_section">
   <!--- new content -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Then for ajax:

```
$.get('path/to/server/', data, function(response){
   /* create object from response*/
   var $newHtml=$(response);
    /* search response object for proper html to insert*/
    $('#first_section').html( $newHtml.find('#first_section').html());
     /* match for second section*/
})
```

Comment: I am accepting your answer. I did not know that you can create a JQuery object from a plain string so .find can be called on it.  Also, this is not a JSON application. Right? Can you enlighten me on that? Thanks.

Comment: no json involved...like I said, you could return a full html page and do this. JSON is just a format for data delivery but ajax works with numerous formats

Comment: I saw one of the answers above and it occurred to me(as suggested in the answer) that JSON Object can be generated on the server side with two properties and each property having a full HTML markup string as value. The question is, which would be more efficient in this case? Time in terms of parsing the entire string would be on the client side if pure HTML as suggested by you and me is generated on the server side. With JSON, the individuals property values can be assigned right away. Is that correct? Sorry to seek clarification here. I am not a fan of JSON.

Comment: If you get time to read this...     var $response_html=$(response);
console.log($response_html.find('#login_history').html());  If response has a div with id of login_history, why am I getting undefined in the console?

Comment: if not wrapped in a root element , try `filter()` instead of `find()`

Comment: Yup! It worked. Thanks a lot!! I'll look into the documentation to understand why.

Comment: that's why i noted the root element in my code, `find()` is for descendants, filter is for same level

Comment: At the risk of inviting your ire... All display works well as expected. I have several sections and the response gets split and copied to the correct Divs. But I have one problem.  I have JS in it through <script> tags which does not get executed. I think I am missing some fundamental understanding here. Any quick comment for me to look into? So <div id="A"><div id="inner_div">....</div> <script>some JS</script></div> When $('#A')'s html() from the AJAX response is copied to a target div, how do I get the JS in the script tag to execute?

Comment: `html()` method removes scripts. Would be better to have that script called in main page, after the content is inserted, or can use `$.getScript` which is ajax way to get a script file which will run automatically once received

Comment: Promise that this is my last question... "html() method removes script" does that mean that if response from AJAX has script tags and using your answer, I copy section to a target div, then the script in the response is "lost" in the transfer? What do you mean by "have that script called in main page, after the content is inserted?"

Comment: yes...html() will lose the script tags. This is a safety outlet so scripts don't get run unexpectedly when moving elements around in a page

Comment: if you can copy that script, put it in right after you insert the new html in code above

Answer (score 2):

You should return the result as JSON instead of plain text. That way you can return an array or object with 2 properties.

Comment: Please see my update. Response is markup intensive not structured data.

Comment: Upvoted your comment too. You mean that each property of the JSON object can be assigned any HTML markup string? Just realized that, if so, may be JSON is appropriate. I know that jSON (or for that matter ANYTHING) can be generated on server.

Answer (score 2):

In such things is hard to say what option is better, or the right option.
But, you can do something like this:

> response= `<div class="_section1"></div> <div class="_sectio2"></div>`

```
$getJSON("url", {data=""}, function(result){
 var $html = result;
 $('#target_div1').html($html.find("._section1")[0]);
 $('#target_div2').html($html.find("._section2")[1]);
```

});