# Ajax related queries using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a html and php file.

I'm using d3 to draw charts in the html file and php file for ajax.

In the HTML file I have a function similar to this to draw d3 charts

**Chart Function :**

```
function draw_chart(reference, data) {
   // chart function.....   
}
```

**AJAX SCRIPT :**

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "data.php",
            data: { value:value },
            async: true,
            dataType: 'json'
        }).done(function(result) {
            div_name = '#chart_div';

            draw_chart(div_name, result);
        })
```

And of course this is working very fine.

In the PHP file I've connected to a PostgreSQL data and I'm able to do everything successfully.

But along with the chart I wanted to update a table now.

If I write another query in the PHP file and echo it.

How will I be able to separate that result and append it to table?

Only work around that I know to my knowledge is creating another PHP file for the table.

And one more is to write the entire javascript function in PHP file and using jquery `.html` file to append it.

But I wanted to do it the way I said above. Is there any possibilities on doing it like separating it and appending the separated data to the table?

I actually don't know whether it can be done or not or might was asked earlier too.

Someone help me out.

Comment: What does your PHP return? How is the output formated? Plain text, JSON? You can encode the data as JSON on the server side and parse it in jQuery on you page.

Comment: For the chart I'm returning json. And for the table it's a plain text.

Comment: So you can just append the text to your JSON object. Just add the text to your array/object in PHP before encoding to JSON and then parse it in jQuery... just like you do for the d3 values.

Comment: But in the AJAX result I get both JSON and Plain Text. How do I separate it?

Comment: That's what I'm saying .... don't output both JSON and text. Add the text to the JSON object and output only JSON.

Comment: Then just get the JSON for you d3 graphs and the text for the table.

Comment: I got it. Let me give it a try and get back.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have this in PHP:

```
//an array of results from the db you what to draw your charts with
 $my_results_array=get_from_db();

//then somewhere you encode it to json 
echo json_encode($my_result_array);

//then you output the text for the table
 echo $table_text;
```

What I'm saying is add the $table_text to the end of your array and encode it.

```
array_push($my_results_array,$table_text);
echo json_encode($my_results_array);
```

And then just get the text from the last position on you JSON object in JS.

Comment: I have two queries. And I convert the 1st query to JSON using `json_encode()`. And the 2nd query result. I need to append each row to a table by creating `echo '<tr>' . sqlresult['colname'] . '</tr>'` by using while function in PHP. I won't be able to do it like the way you said I guess so and the rows returned for the 2nd query is k's.

Comment: Here's the output. `[{"label":"label","label1":"67041","label2":"745","label3":"45191","label4":"11464"}]<table id="table"></table>`. I tried following [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20804960/processing-ajax-response-consisting-of-two-logically-separate-html-markup-sectio). But nothing fruitful. Help me out?

Comment: Make a new array with the other two arrays as it elements then encode that to JSON and on the client side just decode it and use the first object for your charts and loop through the second to update your table.

Comment: Something like this: `$newArray[0]=$my_sql_results1; $newArray[0]=$my_sql_results2; echo json_encode($newArray);`

Comment: Then you can access the two arrays, objects as elements of the main JSON object in js. Something like `result[0] , result[1]` .. use the first for your charts, loop through the second one for your table.